# Publish over FTP issue - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have been struggling to get the Publish over FTP to successfully transfer my DotNetCore build artifact from my Jenkins Linux slave to my AzurePack server. This plugin worked for the same host and target server in the conventional Jenkins pipeline.

I would like to know why it is saying the transfer was successful when 0 files were transferred?
I would also like to know why it is not transferring any files when I am listing the source directory before and after the `ftpPublish` call and all of the files are being listed?

I would also like to know what should be in the `paramPublish` variable?

Below is my groovy code:

[Publish over FTP stage in JPaC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0ah3.png)

Below is my console output from Jenkins:

[Jenkins Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1g5J.png)

Comment: please add your code here as well as the console output. do not use screenshots, since search engines won't be able to guide other users with the same problem to this page.

Comment: Code is in the attached images

Comment: that is exactly what you should not do. please paste the code as text in your question and do NOT link images with code. Thank you :)

Comment: Do you have the Jenkins domain knowledge to answer my question?

Comment: I hope you understood @Michael's intention here, it has nothing to do with whether or not he has jenkins knowledge and whether he is able to answer your question, 4 years later here I am searching for a solution to a similar problem, had your code been in text in your question, I would have found this post sooner(ranked higher by google), and by the way your code has shown me what I am missing in my ftpPublisher command.